# Cmd.exe closes during "for" command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Cmd.exe is closing and terminating a batch file during the execution of the for command. Can anyone help me to modify the .bat file so it will run to completion?

Batch file has the following lines:

```
start "" "autohotkey.exe" "p:\script.ahk"

timeout /t 3

cd C:\windows\system32\wbem

for /f %D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "EHD_BACKUP"') do set myDrive=%D

timeout /t -1

cd C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt
```

Using the pause command I have determined the .bat file runs fine up until the execution of the "for" command when CMD.exe automatically closes, which prevents the batch file from completing.

When I run the "for" command in the command window by itself (outside of the .bat file) it runs as expected and provides the expected response for the `myDrive` variable.  However it returns 2 prompts after running successfully - as follows:

```
C:\windows\system32>for /f %D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "EHD_BACKUP"') do set myDrive=%D

C:\windows\system32>set myDrive=K:

C:\windows\system32>
```

How can I modify my batch file so it doesn't close during the for command?  The double line response to for is unusual and I suspect it is the cause of this issue but do not know how to address it.

Comment: In your batch script after the for command you have `cd C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt.exe`, is `VeraCrypt.exe` the name of a directory? You'll also probably want to surround the path with quotes since there's a space between `Program` and `Files`.

Comment: Hi - that was my error in typing the question.  The .bat file  actually says CD c:\program files\veracrypt    (I incorrectly added .exe).  I corrected this in my orig question.  The problem is my .bat file terminates before ever reaching this command - it terminates when it runs the for /f %D .... line.  Thanks!

Comment: When you start your batch from a cmd window, instead from a explorer click , then you would see the error message `D can't be processed here`.  That's because the FOR command expects a double percent inside batch files (like the HELP FOR explains)

Answer (score 0):

You must use %% instead of % before the variable

> { % variable | %% variable } : Required. Represents a replaceable parameter. Use %variable to carry out for from the command prompt. Use %%variable to carry out the for command within a batch file. Variables are case-sensitive and must be represented with an alpha value, such as %A, %B, or %C.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: It is also possible to use other characters than alphabetic characters like `#` or `$`  as loop variable. I prefer usage of  `#` for my own batch files as loop variable if no need for multiple loop variables because of using multiple tokens. `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. are just better in general because of `tokens=1,3,5-8*` for example on which first token is assigned to loop variable `A`, third token to next variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `B`, and so on.